# Is there another way of obtaining /usr/bin/mysql_config --plugindir on Redhat?

Tags: mysql, redhat

On my debian boxes I can easily get this value from `/usr/bin/mysql_config --plugindir` when building a MySQL UDF library. However on Redhat this option does not appear to be a flag on the `mysql_config` binary so it just errors.

MySQL on Redhat is at 5.0.77 and on Debian it is at 5.1.37 so perhaps this could also be the cause?

I am unsure and it is the last problem halting a completed build. Any ideas of how I can obtain this value or get Redhats `mysql_config` to return the right thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no. MySQL did not support plugins until 5.1.